# Advantages and disadvantages of normalisation

Tags: normalization

Briefly, what are the main advantages and disadvantages of normalisation as a technique for database design?

It may be easier to answer this with a snapshot of some unorganised data, as a concrete example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Microsoft article that does a pretty good job explaining [**normalization and the different forms**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description), albeit a little dated regarding Microsoft Access, the theory and principles still apply.

In short, database **normalization** employs the following benefits:

1. Reduces data redundancy which improves maintainability. As you see in your example table `Customer_Sale`, things that aren't central to a **Sale** are repeated unnecessarily.

   A good example of this is the `ItemDesc` column. Imagine the scenario where `ItemNo = 123` has been sold to `Customers` for the past year, **10s of thousands** of sales for example. And then the business realizes the `ItemDesc` is wrong and needs to be updated. With the current **denormalized** design of storing the `ItemDesc` in the `Customer_Sale` table, you would need to update all **10s of thousands** of records to fix the `ItemDesc`.

   **Normalization** would be to have another table called `Items` which would store one row per unique `Item` and is where the `ItemDesc` would live. The primary key of that table would likely be the `ItemNo` (assuming that's the unique identifier for an `Item` here). So there would only be one record for `ItemNo = 123` with the `ItemDesc` column in the `Items` table. The `Customer_Sale` table would no longer have a column called `ItemDesc` (you'd be able to reference it in the `Items` table by joining on the `ItemNo` field in both tables). Now if the description of an `Item` needs to change, you'd only have to update it in one place, that single row in the `Items` table.
2. For similar reasons this would improve performance, by minimizing the amount of work the above type of maintenance requires. Less rows to update generally means shorter lock times and less chance of lock escalation (when applicable). So overall your database system and the applications that consume it will be able to run more efficiently.
3. Another reason performance may improve due to **normalization** is because your tables (and more so the objects they live in on the disk - generally referred to as data pages) become smaller in data size.

   This helps improve the performance of a SQL engine when locating and loading those data pages off the disk, which is typically the biggest bottleneck in a server's provisioned hardware. Since your table and effectively its rows become smaller in size, that means more rows can be fit in a single data page, which means less pages would need to be located and loaded off the disk as a result too.
4. From the consuming application perspective, you also generally gain more flexibility when the architecture of your database is **normalized** appropriately.

   By having the fields of your data points broken out into appropriately less wide tables, that make general sense to your domain model, and keeping the closely related fields of a particular entity together in the same table, you maximize your ability to utilize, query, and manipulate those data points and entities as needed in your consuming applications (a refactoring of your data in a very loose sense of the word).

   An example of this again using your `Customer_Sale` table would be if you had a **Sales Order** application that has two screens. One that was the unique list of `Items` the business sells with their descriptions, and the other was the list of `Customer_Sales` that have been made by the business so far.

   If you didn't have the **normalized** `Items` table that stored the `ItemDesc` field (as my first point exemplified) then to support both of those screens and their use cases, you'd have a more difficult time with the less flexible **denormalized** `Customer_Sale` table because of its data redundancy for the `Items` information.

   Of course in your consuming programming language you can use a distinct operator of sorts to transform the data of your `Customer_Sale` table to fit the model of the `Items` available for selling screen, but that is an additional set of work that the consuming application needs to do every time that screen is loaded. It also becomes dicey fast with managing the code, especially as more complex business rules come into play over time as opposed to a **normalized** database architecture where the `Items` table already exists.

Possible disadvantages of **normalization** are:

1. **Over-normalization** can lead to potential performance problems. By breaking the fields up into too many tables, it may overcomplicate querying that always involves re-joining most of those tables back together to get the rows you need. Some database systems struggle harder with too many joins, but your mileage may vary.
2. In a database structure meant to support heavy **OLAP** (**Online Analytical Processing** - essentially data warehousing and heavy reporting purposess) sometimes **denormalized** tables perform better by keeping *cached* and *pre-calculated* commonly needed **facts and figures** nearby.

There's a lot more in-depth and technical reasoning not discussed in this answer that is in the article I linked at the start of this answer. So I highly recommend reading through that article after getting a very brief overview from this answer.

Comment: That link's descriptions of NFs are wrong & not helpful to describe or justify normalization. See a good textbook or other reasonable research.